# Excel - Finding out whether or not criteria is met on list with duplicate references

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an excel sheet, I'm trying to find certain values on a list based on references that are duplicated on this list. I'm not sure how to explain this properly so here's an example:

This is my starting point:

[image: Initial list]

Now I need to fill in the empty cells below with either a Yes or No:

[image: What i want to populate]

I've tried doing this with a mix of vlookups and if functions but I haven't been able to find a way to make it work because of the duplicates on my first list. Any kind of lookup I've tried stops as soon as it finds the first match.

Appreciate any help I can get.

PS: first post here, I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Countifs()

Assuming initial list is in A:B and your table is c1:f6, d2 should be

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$C2,$B:$B,D$1)>1,"yes","no")
```